# How to get a column that has custom values based on data in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plsql

I have a couple of tables which have information about an activity(like an article), how do I get a column back that spits out a value based on some condition

| Learner | Certificate view dt |
| --- | --- |
| First | 2023-10-09 |
| Second | 2024-01-03 |

| Learner | Certificate valid date |
| --- | --- |
| First | 2023-07-09 |
| Second | 2024-02-23 |

For example I want to get some data through some comparisons(could be a different condition too) like

`if(certificate view dt < certificate valid date) then return 'qualified' otherwise return 'unqualified'`

ultimately I want to get something like this

| Learner | Status |
| --- | --- |
| First | qualified |
| Second | unqualified |

How to achieve that in sql or do I need something like a PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 2):

With [CASE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-case/)

```
SELECT 
  Learner,
  CASE WHEN (certificate_view_dt < certificate_valid_date) 
    THEN 'qualified' 
    ELSE 'unqualified' 
  END AS status
FROM my_table
```

see [online demo](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/42668eet3)

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  learner VARCHAR(50),
  certificate_view_dt DATE,
  certificate_valid_date DATE
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO my_table (learner, certificate_view_dt, certificate_valid_date)
VALUES 
    ('First', '2023-10-09', '2023-07-09'),
    ('Second', '2024-01-03', '2024-02-23');


-- fetch 
SELECT 
  Learner,
  CASE WHEN (certificate_view_dt < certificate_valid_date) 
    THEN 'qualified' 
    ELSE 'unqualified' 
  END AS status
FROM my_table
```

output

```
 learner |   status    
---------+-------------
 First   | unqualified
 Second  | qualified
```

Comment: It is throwing a syntax error at 'AS' status. Anything about it ?

Comment: I have missed `END`. I have updated the response

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @SimoneNigro is correct, except your data being split into two tables (I cannot see why you would do this but I'll assume you have a valid reason). Since you have two tables it is necessary to *consolidate* them into single tuple for each `learner`. You use [join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html) to accomplish that. Resulting query becomes: (see [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/O7rn14d4))

```sql
select learner,
       case when certificate_view_dt < certificate_valid_date
            then 'qualified'
            else 'unqualified'
       end status
from certificate_view
left join certificate_valid using(learner);
```

| learner | status |
| --- | --- |
| First | unqualified |
| Second | qualified |
| Third | unqualified |

Demo adds learner *Third* to `certificate_view` but not to `certificate_valid` to show what happens with a missing row in one of the tables. Depending upon your data conditions the query may need corresponding adjustments.